# Doesn't return profile photo

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-3.8, py-telegram-bot-api

```
print(update.message.bot.get_user_profile_photos(update.effective_user.id, 0))
```

When a chat with a bot is open, it returns a profile photo, otherwise it returns `{'total_count': 0, 'photos': []}`. Is it possible to make the profile photo always return?

Answer (score 1):

You will get this if your privacy setting is set to this:

[image: Privacy settings]